# Animate a parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

Plotei uma curva paramétrica usando o tikz, mas preciso animá-la. Mas não consigo criar a animação em cima do parâmetro. Estou usando também o pacote animate.

I plotted a parametric curve using tikz, but I need to animate it. But I can't create the animation on top of the parameter. I am also using the animate package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Unfortunately, we operate exclusively in English.  Could you translate your question?

Comment: Bem vinda ao TeX.SX! Neste site usamos apenas o idioma Inglês, para que o máximo de pessoas possa ler e entender a sua pergunta e respostas. Poderia traduzir, por favor?  Também mostre-nos o que você já conseguiu fazer (um [exemplo mínimo compilável](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. In addition to translating your question, you really need to show us a small document that shows what you're doing. The document should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}` and include the relevant packages (`tikz`, and related libraries) plus `animate`. This will greatly help in getting you some help.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purpose.

Compile the following code with `latex` twice (2 times) followed by `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`. You will see a beautiful shape that will change your life.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\Delta{round(2*pi/30:1)}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,loop]{10}
\multiframe{31}{n=0.0+\Delta}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
    \psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15},linecolor=red]{0}{\n}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

I don't show the output of the curve on purpose.